# Firebase. AdMob. Rewarded video. Does not work correctly on fragments

Tags: android, firebase, admob, fragment, rewardedvideoad

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but... I use 1 activity and something fragments. When I run ads (rewarded video) on the third fragment, after viewing the advertisement, it sends me to the first fragment of my activity. Errors do not produce any, launching downloads and advertisements as well as in the description from Google.